# Starting arguments: What are the controversial areas of our scope?

Tags: discussion

Are there any areas of our scope for which we don't have many questions yet and haven't tested the community reaction? What topics are likely to cause disagreement? Not obviously on topic, not obviously off topic. We need questions on these topics in order to explore our limits, so I'd like to see what people currently think is underrepresented and unexplored on the main site.

Comment: Martin [mentioned some underrepresented topics in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23300289#23300289) but chat doesn't seem to have been very active at the time. I'd particularly like to see topics that are not only underrepresented but also on the border of our scope so we can map the territory of this site.

Comment: I like to draw the territory of this site. What about Computer Vision, Image Processing? There is a proposal for these topics on area51 so i don't know if we can accept that topics on this site.

Comment: @psicomante whether something is on topic elsewhere does not affect whether something is on topic here. Asking a few questions on main should show whether this community welcomes them.